# Why is Spring not talking to me? (Or: How do I correctly configure Spring logging?)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-security, log4j2

My actual problem is with Spring Security and configuring OAuth2 for an authentication server, but to trace my problem there I would like Spring to tell me what actually happens, when a request reaches an endpoint. I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and the logging starter `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`and actually it seems to work quite well. My log4j2-configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configuration>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%-5level%d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X %logger{36}%n  %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  <File name="File" fileName="logs/application.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%-5level%d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X %logger{36} %msg%n"/>
  </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>    
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When booting up the application (embedded Tomcat) I can see that the configuraiton actually is used and Spring logs a lot of stuff during the process:

```
...
INFO Feb 02, 2018 11:31:00.295 [restartedMain] {} org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry
  HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@41229bd4
INFO Feb 02, 2018 11:31:00.345 [restartedMain] {} org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
  Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
DEBUG Feb 02, 2018 11:31:00.440 [restartedMain] {} org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory
  Looking up query for method findByEmail
...
```

But when I send a request to the application to obtain an Oauth2 access token receiving an 4xx-error I would like Spring to tell me what it does so that I can find my configuration error. But it does not log anything. I see Hiberante stuff and my own logging but Spring remains silent. I would expect a lot of messages due to the TRACE-configuration.

Can anybody imagine, what I'm doing wrong? Or is Spring simply not talkative?

*UPDATE 02/08/2018:*
It seems that my problem is bound to Spring Security. I did some debugging and found different loggers for Spring Security and other parts of the framework.
For example in `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory`Spring is using the logger `org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger` (which is set to DEBUG in my configuration), but Spring security uses `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger` for example in `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy` (which is set to INFO despite my log4j2 configuration).

So I tried to debug into the code where the logger of `FilterChainProxy` is assigned. But unfortunately the code is either never reached or my breakpoints do not work. I guess it is the second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem myself:
Spring widely uses *slf4J* for logging. For that I included a bridge in my project, which works perfectly well and produces the log output in my question.
But Spring Security (and maybe other parts of Spring too) uses *Apache Commons Logging* which is no problem by itself since *Spring 5* comes with *spring.jcl* which is among other things a bridge from *Apache Commons Logging* to *log4J2*.
But here is the devilish thing: I inluded another library that has a transitive dependency to *common-logging* and so inlucdes the direct implementation of "Apache Commons Logging" into my project. So I had two different `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` classes in my classpath. Spring security decided to use the implementation in *commons-logging* instead of the one in *spring-jcl* and of course therefore my log4j-configuration did not influence the loggers of Spring security.

Actually all I had to do is exclude *commons-logging* in my build-file and let *spring-jcl* do its work again.

Comment: Thank your for the  hint, Fancer! I also found a relevant Spring issue, where Juergen Hoeller recommends to do the same: _"For a newly started project, no extra setup is necessary in the first place: Let spring-jcl do its job, picking up Log4J 2 or SLF4J or JUL by default, with no need for excludes or bridges. If you'd like to consistently use spring-jcl that way, you should simply exclude commons-logging and/or jcl-over-slf4j dependencies in other libraries that might bring those into your classpath by default."_

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20611

Answer (score 0):

One option is to extend `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher` which will let you hook into auth success/failure. Of course you would replace the print statements with your own logging.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher extends DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher {

    @Override
    public void publishAuthenticationSuccess(Authentication authentication) {
        super.publishAuthenticationSuccess(authentication);
        System.out.println("AUTH SUCCESS " + authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public void publishAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationException exception, Authentication authentication) {
        super.publishAuthenticationFailure(exception, authentication);
        System.out.println("AUTH ERROR " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for that hint! It might enable me to dig into my problem regarding OAuth2. But still I would like Spring to be more talkative. When I use such a `CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher` to hook into the authentication process, I can see a lot of debug-statements in the Spring code before the call to `publishAuthenticationFailure`. However the logger in for example `BasicAuthenticationFilter#doFilterInternal` is not set to TRACE level , but INFO. So Spring is completely ignoring my log4j2-configuration.